# Handle url with .html extension in angular2 router?

Tags: oauth, salesforce, angular2-routing

We are working on a Angular2(created from angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.28.3) which connects to Salesforce via OAth's User-Agent Flow mechanism(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/vppravi93/1944d2b072f88d3fe8c076970acd3375) is the authentication code i've used in the code.
Here's the code which handles the callback after Authentication:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ForceService } from './force';

@Component({
  template : ` `,
})
export class AuthComponent {

  constructor(force : ForceService) { 
     var event = new CustomEvent("oauthCallback", {'detail': window.location.href});
     window.opener.document.dispatchEvent(event); 
     window.close();   
  }
}
```

In Salesforce, we have something called Connected-App, where we configure the callback urls for the authentication. Callbacks url looks like below:
***https://my.site.com/#/auth-callback***. Angular2 router configuration uses **useHash:true** option as well.

Everything is working fine until the new requirement which needs only the callback url to point to something like this:
***https://my.site.com/auth-callback.html***

So the equivalent html code for above will be :

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var event = new CustomEvent("oauthCallback", {'detail': window.location.href});
        window.opener.document.dispatchEvent(event); 
        window.close();   
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Problem, we face is after Authenticating, we are not able to access the `access_token` from the url and close the Authentication Window, since the routing is not properly redirecting to `auth-callback.html`. All we get is a blank screen with url changed to ***http://localhost:4200/#/access_token***

Is there's a way to solve this issue without turning off **useHash** ?

Comment: When you look at the web dev console, do you see a 404 on the blank screen?

Comment: No, I don't see such log in the console tab.

Comment: I've only dealt with the html5mode implementation, which is the alternative to useHash.  My guess is you might be better off having `http://localhost:4200` be the callback URL and have some logic in the app component to recognize the call needs to be routed.  Is the app setup such that `http://localhost:4200/index.html` is the location of the router outlet?  By the sounds of it, the callback is hitting the Angular index and it tries to find the matching route on its own.

Comment: So, what you are saying is, setup a router path something `{ path: '', component: AuthComponent }` and handle the redirection logic based on the url parameters?.

Comment: Something along those lines.  I'm sure I don't understand your setup as well as you, but that's my thought.  I think you'd want to let your routing/angular code do the heavy lifting as opposed to an external resource/redirect link.  If you don't want to put the logic in the router, you could have your app component check for the auth payload and have some logic to route where you want.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. Let me try what you suggested and get back.

Comment: @Praveen Hii, can you send link of salesforce OAuth login example, I want it for reference

Comment: @sagarpatel Please use this link : http://coenraets.org/blog/2015/12/angular2-rest-salesforce/

Comment: @Praveen Thanks for help
Anyone who looking for angular4 + salesforce API integration + persistence login refers this link: https://github.com/byteparity/ngx-salesforce